# Pandas datetime: find the correct year for the first date after a datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I started with a dataframe as follows:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     {'date1': ['10/02/2012', '10/02/2012', 'NA/NA/2014', 'NA/NA/2014', '01/02/2014'],
    ...:     'date2': ['10-Nov', '19-Oct', '26-Nov', '23-Oct', '14-Oct'],
    ...:     'date3': ['30/06/2011', '30/06/2011', '30/06/2013', '30/06/2013', 'NA']})
    ...:

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
        date1   date2       date3
0  10/02/2012  10-Nov  30/06/2011
1  10/02/2012  19-Oct  30/06/2011
2  NA/NA/2014  26-Nov  30/06/2013
3  NA/NA/2014  23-Oct  30/06/2013
4  01/02/2014  14-Oct  NA
```

I have managed to convert the dates into datetime objects. Therefore I have the following dataframe:

```
In [26]: df["date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date1"], errors="coerce", dayfirst=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
    ...: df["date3"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date3"], errors="coerce", dayfirst=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
    ...: df["date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date2"], errors="coerce", dayfirst=True, format="%d-%b")
    ...: df
    ...:
Out[26]:
       date1      date2      date3
0 2012-02-10 1900-11-10 2011-06-30
1 2012-02-10 1900-10-19 2011-06-30
2        NaT 1900-11-26 2013-06-30
3        NaT 1900-10-23 2013-06-30
4 2014-01-02 1900-10-14        NaT
```

Because `date2` had no `year` encoding set all the `year` values to `1900`.

However, I need the first date in `date2` that was reached AFTER `date3` and this datetime's associated `year`.

ALSO NOTE:

When `date3` is `NaT` I need to look backwards from `date1` to fill in the year of `date2`. This can be seen in `df.iloc[4,:]`

So I want the output dateframe to be:

```
       date1      date2      date3
0 2012-02-10 2011-11-10 2011-06-30
1 2012-02-10 2011-10-19 2011-06-30
2        NaT 2013-11-26 2013-06-30
3        NaT 2013-10-23 2013-06-30
4 2014-01-02 2013-10-14        NaT
```

This is harder than just using `date3.year` because sometimes `date3` is late in the year (e.g. `30/12/2013` -> `2013-12-30`) and so `date2` will be the first date in the next year (i.e. `14-Oct` -> `1900-10-14` -> `2014-10-14`).

Furthermore, when this returns `nan` I need my datetime to be robust enough to return NaT.

#### So I need to find the next following `year` AFTER `date3` which matches the `day-month` in `date2`. Or if that's missing, I need the `year` BEFORE `date1` which matches the `day-month` in `date2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply m-d compare with date2 and date3

```
pd.to_datetime(((df.date2.dt.strftime('%m%d')<df.date3.dt.strftime('%m%d')).astype(int)+df.date3.dt.year).astype(str)+'-'+df.date2.dt.strftime('%m-%d'))
Out[62]: 
0   2011-11-10
1   2011-10-19
2   2013-11-26
3   2013-10-23
4   2013-10-14
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: The problem here is that I have some NaTs in the date2 column. Therefore, `df.date3.dt.year` returns an object of `dtype == float`. 

Therefore, the returning string before passing into `pd.to_datetime()` is `"2011.0-11-10"`. 

The series looks like this `pd.Series(["2011.0-11-10", "2011.0-10-19", "2013.0-11-26", "2013.0-10-23", "2013.0-10-14"])`.

Comment: @TommyLees you can fillna with some year link fillna(1970), then should all fixed

Comment: An added complexity (will update the question to reflect) because sometimes `date1` exists but `date2` does not. In which case I need to do the opposite and look backwards from `date1`. Could I do the same as yours but backwards, create 2 datetime `Series` and `join` them, excluding `NaT`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help